# Laravel eloquent query order by customized field

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have this raw mysql query

```
SELECT campaign_influencers.*, 
   CASE influencer_status 
     WHEN 'PENDING' THEN 0 
     WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 
     WHEN 'LIVE' THEN 2 
     WHEN 'ACCEPTED' THEN 3 
     ELSE 5 
   end AS order_field 
FROM   campaign_influencers 
WHERE  campaign_id = 612 
ORDER  BY order_field
```

How can this be converted to eloquent query builder?

This is what I have done so far.

```
 $sql = "SELECT campaign_influencers.*, 
               CASE influencer_status 
                 WHEN 'PENDING' THEN 3 
                 WHEN 'ACTIVE' THEN 1 
                 WHEN 'LIVE' THEN  2
                 WHEN 'ACCEPTED' THEN 0 
                 ELSE 5 
               end AS order_field 
            FROM   campaign_influencers 
            WHERE  campaign_id = :campaignId 
            ORDER  BY order_field";


 $campaignInfluencers = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), array(
        'campaignId' => $id
    ));
```

Only issues is that the relationship object is gone.

```
foreach ($campaignInfluencers as $campaignInfluencer) {
    $user = $campaignInfluencer->user;    //will not work
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: planning to do a db:raw.    $results = DB::select( DB::raw($sql), array(
                'campaignId' => $campaignId
    ));

Comment: Can you please give feedback on the answers?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```php
CampaignInfluencer::select('*', DB::raw('CAST influencer_status ... AS order_field'))
    ->where('campaign_id', $campaign_id)
    ->orderBy('order_field')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten your query by using [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT campaign_influencers.*, 
       FIND_IN_SET(influencer_status,'ACCEPTED,LIVE,ACTIVE,PENDING') AS order_field 
FROM   campaign_influencers 
WHERE  campaign_id = 612 
ORDER  BY order_field DESC
```

Using eloquent as @Jonas Staudenmeir already suggested you need to use `raw` method for raw sql expressions

```
YourModel::select('*', DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(influencer_status,'ACCEPTED,LIVE,ACTIVE,PENDING') AS order_field"))
    ->where('campaign_id', 612)
    ->orderBy('order_field', 'desc')
    ->get();
```